CORS Issues with Backend for Frontend (BFF) in .NET Core API and Angular using Keycloak
I'm trying to implement a Backend for Frontend (BFF) architecture using a .NET Core API and an Angular app. The identity provider I'm using is Keycloak.
When the Angular app starts, it makes an HTTP GET request to my endpoint api/auth/login, which is implemented as follows:
[HttpGet("login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Challenge();
    }

    return Ok(new { message = "Authenticated user" });
}

When the Angular app calls the api/auth/login endpoint, I receive the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/realms/xyz/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...'
from origin 'https://localhost:44315/api/auth/login' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Current CORS configuration in my .NET Core API:
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularApp",
        builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") 
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials());
});
app.UseCors("AllowAngularApp");

Keycloak Configuration:
Web Origins:

https://localhost:44315
http://localhost:4200

Valid Redirect URIs:

https://localhost:44315/*
http://localhost:4200/*

If I call the api/auth/login endpoint directly from the browser, I'm correctly redirected to the Keycloak login page, where I can successfully log in. Once the login is complete, I can see the authentication token and cookies set in the browser console.
The scenario I'm trying to implement: Angular should call the .NET Core API endpoint, which in turn should redirect the user to the Keycloak login page. Once the user logs in, I should set the authentication cookie, and everything should work seamlessly.
Despite these configurations, I'm still getting CORS errors. How should I properly configure my .NET Core API and Keycloak to implement the BFF pattern and resolve these CORS issues?
Any suggestions on how to handle this setup or best practices for implementing BFF in this context would be greatly appreciated.

The error is caused by the fact that you are redirecting the HTTP request from Javascript to your identity provider, which is not ok with that.
Your back-end should not be redirecting this kind of requests; there should be some kind of error (like a 401 status code) that tells the front-end that actually it needs to authenticate the user.
